# Microsoft Master Data Services 2016 Additonal Domain Atrribute Referencing

Tags: master-data-services

Is it possible to reference additional columns apart from the 'Code' and 'Name' columns when using a domain attribute in an entity?

E.g. A person entity has a code of '**1**' and a name of '**Smith**' and a Gender of '**Male**'

In a customer entity there is a domain value referencing the person entity which displays the following 1 {Smith}. The users would like an additional read only attribute which would copy the Gender value of 'Male' into the customer entity based on the domain value. Can this be done using out of the box MDS UI?

I know this is duplicate data and breaks normal form but for usability this would be useful. It would be the equivalent of referencing additional columns in an MS Access drop down list.

Many thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the standard UI. One option would be to develop a custom UI where you can handle these kind of requests.

If you want to stick with the standard product I can see a workaround but this is a bit of a "dirty" one.

You can misuse (abuse) the Name attribute of the Person entity by adding a business rule to the Person entity that generates the content of the Name attribute as a concatenation of multiple attributes. You of course need an additional attribute that serves as a place holder for the original Name. The concatenated field will then show in your customer entity.

One question that does come to mind is why a user would like/need to see the gender of a person in a customer list? As you have a separate Person entity I expect you to have multiple persons per customers. What would the gender of one person - even if it is the main contact - matter?